# How can I open .csv files on Excel if Excel isn't in the list?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, csv

After my laptop got formatted, .csv files are opening only through Notepad. I want .csv files to open with Excel always.

For this, I tried changing its default app to Excel, but unfortunately got no option like Excel as an app to open .csv files.

Here is a screenshot of the same:

[image]

I would also like to share that I have Excel installed on my laptop, here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

And here is the screen shot of Microsoft office:

[image]

As suggested in comments below, I right clicked on the .csv file, but got no options to open them with Excel. Here are the screen shots of the same:

[image]

[image]

I even clicked on more apps, but got no option like Excel.

Can anybody kindly help me to set Excel as my default app to open .csv files?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is Excel installed? And are you sure it's not the web-only version?

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for helping me. I have updated my question in order to show that I have Microsoft Excel installed.

Comment: Is MS Excel 2010 the most recent version you have installed?

Comment: @shoover Yes, this is the most recent version of Excel on my laptop

Comment: Actually, another person from HP came to format my laptop. So, he had installed this version of Excel. I doubt whether it is the latest version available in the market.

Comment: @John could we just forget suggesting SFC for *any* question that comes up with Windows? Official people on MS sites do this every time, no matter what the question is about. App assignment to extensions is very clearly not something that should be SFC'd, it's a simple user setting.

Comment: Open with: choose another app. locate excel. bingo!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Right click the file, choose open with. If Excel is not showing, select more apps, then chose option to browse. Browse for Excel and choose it. You can also check to always use this type of app for the file type within the same options.

Comment: just adding another option, use Import data from CSV from Excel might be an option too , from Data Tab , then look for menu "From Text/CSV" ,  this way there's gonna be a menu to show options (delimiters, data type) during importing the csv data to the table layout of excel.

Comment: Yes, I implemented this method also in order to open CSV files, but it becomes difficult when we have too many CSV files to open and we always have to import CSV, select delimiter, and only then read them in excel.

Comment: If Your computer really does not like Excel for some reason you may need to use the "find another app on this PC" option and hunt down the .exe manually. Do this beforehand by right clicking any link to excel itself and use the "open file location" option, then copy the path. This works 100% as long as you have excel installed

Comment: @Hobbamok Actually, some versions of Excel don't work like this; they give themselves magic CLSID links, so you can't open file location. (The executables are still there, though, if you manually navigate to them in (probably) Program Files.)

Answer (score 9):

[Emily's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1661862) is what I'd suggest if it wasn't already posted, as it covers actually locating Excel on the PC.

But, as more of a side note that seems a little too useful to leave in a comment: if you want to quickly open a file in Excel *without* needing to associate it with Excel, you can open Excel first, then open File Explorer and navigate to where your .csv file is, then drag the .csv file into the blank Excel window. (This works for most programs and file types too, not just Excel and .csv files - if you ever need to open something in something it doesn't want to open with by itself, it's worth giving it a try.)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting one more useful answer.

Answer (score 7):

Which Office do you have? Could other formats of Office files (.xls, .xlsx and etc) be opened successfully via Excel?

As you said your laptop got formatted, please ensure your Office is installed on your laptop now.

You may go to Control Panel to have a check.

If the Office exists on you laptop, I suggest you right-click the .csv file > Properties > Change Open with > If there is no Excel app, click More apps > Look for another app on this PC > Locate to Office installation directory (Such as 64-bit Microsoft 365 apps, its path is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16`. For 32-bit version, the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16`) > Find and choose Excel.exe to open .csv file.

If the Office suit is not shown on Control Panel, please log  the account you associated with this version of Office into [www.office.com](https://www.office.com/), [download and the installation content](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-microsoft-365-or-office-2019-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658).